# Pass postgresql schema to alembic migration

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy, alembic

I have a postgresql database and I want to pass postgresql schema name in DSN, like this: `postgresql://login:password@postgreshost/dbname?schema=my_schema`. I know that I can specify the `schema` keyword in migration operations like `op.create_table`. Unfortunately, `upgrade()` and `downgrade()` functions have no arguments in which I can pass postgres schema. Is there any way to pass schema name to `op.create_table()` without hardcoding it?

Comment: Do you **always** want to use that schema as the "default schema"? Ify yes you could change the Postgres user: `alter user the_user set search_path = my_schema` to make all statements default to that schema

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, thank you, now everything works as I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If that should **always** be the default schema, you can change the [schema search path](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-schemas.html#DDL-SCHEMAS-PATH) for the Postgres user:

```
alter user the_user set search_path = my_schema;
```

That will make all statements that use unqualified identifiers use `my_schema` as the default.